# allow CORS policy

Tags: javascript, cors

i want to delete data via ajax, i use PHP for render interface and odoo fro backend service, i am using **CURL** for get API, but i have problem in CORS policy like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL74S.png)

this is my , ajax code

```
$(document).on('click', '#delete_data', function(){    
var id = $(this).data("id"); 
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://localhost:7073/api/delete/petty_cash/",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {          
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",   + "<?php echo $result->access_token;?>");     
        xhr.withCredentials = true; 
    }, 
     contentType : "application/json",
    data: {id:id},       
    success: function() {
        $('.data').load("index.php");
    }, error: function(response){
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

});

and this is my button html code:

```
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete_data" data-id='<?php echo $val['id'] ?>'><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
```

this is my backend code

```
    @http.route([
    '/api/delete/petty_cash/<int:id>'
], type='http', auth="none", methods=['GET'], csrf=False)
@check_valid_token
def delete_petty_cash(self, id, **rec):
    user_id = request.uid
    petty_cash = request.env['petty.cash.app'].\
        search([('create_uid', '=', user_id),
                ('id', '=', id)
                ])
    if petty_cash:
        petty_cash.unlink()
    return valid_response(
        200, {
            "msg" : "Data Deleted",
        }
    )
```

i am using odoo for backend,

i have add this code ini my php code

```
  <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

?>
```

but still CORS not allowed, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

**Read the error message carefully**. Don't pick out the word "CORS" and ignore the rest of the error message.

The error says the problem is that the response to the preflight doesn't have an OK status. It says nothing about an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

If you look up what a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is you'll see that it is an OPTIONS request that is asking permission to make the GET request that you are trying to make.

It doesn't have an OK status so use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to see what the status of it is. I wouldn't be surprised if it was either a 404 NOT FOUND or 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED because your server-side code doesn't have a route for an OPTIONS request, only for a GET request.

Create a suitable route to respond to the preflight request (i.e. with the OPTIONS method) with.

Consider looking for a library / configuration for the framework that you are using which will take care of CORS for you.

Comment: but in my backend code have been testing with postman, and successfull result and the result expected what i want, so how to example code from my issue ?

Comment: Postman is not a browser. It doesn't require permission from CORS to make the request you want to make. If you want to simulate the preflight request in Postman; look in the Network tab to see what shape it has and copy that.